# Is an object's 'this' pointer equal to a pointer to its (single) base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, memory-layout

Given the below:

```
class B
{
  // impl here, can be anything valid for a class
};

class D : public B
{
};

void main()
{
  D real;
  D * pd = &real;
  B * pb = &real;

  // assert(pb == pd);
  // Edit: I meant:
  assert((void *)pb == (void *)pd);
}
```

Is it *guaranteed* by the c++ standard that `pb == pd`? If not, is it always the case in practice? (this is assuming `B` is `D`'s one and only base class)

Comment: No it isn't. Consider an implementation that puts the base class members at the end instead of at the beginning. Legal. Odd, but legal.

Comment: Consider multiple inheritance as well.

Comment: Or not MI but if it were virtual inheritance instead (a case where the base very likely would be placed at the end), however with a single non-virtual base the assert is very likely to be true. I'm pretty sure it is only guaranteed if std::is_standard_layout were true.

Comment: Yes it is guaranteed that `pb == pd`. If you want to ensure that `(void*)pb == (void*)pd`, then no, this is absolutely not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes to the assert, but no to `(void*)pb == (void*)pd` unless they are standard layout types. The latter is also equivalent to reinterpret casting them

Comment: @EJP That's true, but in my example, `D` is (not coincidentally) empty, so I believe putting A's members at the end of B is fine, unless of course it's reordering them, which I highly doubt is acceptable.

Comment: @n.m. Do you have a reference to back that up? Also, the follow up question: 'is it always the case in practice?'

Comment: Yep, read the entire standard. No guarantee found anywhere. Don't know about "always in practice", I dodn't get to try all compilers in all circumstances.

Comment: I have a very vague souvenir of Metrowerks CodeWarrior C++ for Macintosh putting stuff at the end unlike other compilers. That was pre std anyway.

Answer (score 4):

> If not, is it always the case in practice? (this is assuming `B` is `D`'s one and only base class)

Nope. Even that assumption doesn't help. Consider this valid modification:

```
class D : public B
{
  virtual ~D() = default;
};
```

`D` is polymorphic now, while `B` is not. In practice, this means an added pointer for dynamic dispatch. Popularly added at the beginning of the object. So now the `B` sub-object is at an offset, despite being the only base.

It's worth noting, as @melpomene pointed out, that your test would still pass. Since `D*` is implicitly convertible to `B*`, the compiler already does the adjustment for you when you `assert(pb == pd);`. My point was that you can't expect a reinterpret cast (I understood you ask about a flat reinterpretation of the address) to be correct.

Comment: `pb == pd` implicitly converts `pd` to `B *`, which compensates for the offset.

Comment: @melpomene - Yes. But I gathered the OP wonders about a flat reinterpret cast. I could have misunderstood, however.

Comment: Well, OP asked "*Is it guaranteed by the c++ standard that `pb == pd`?*" And OP's code does `assert(pb == pd)`, so it does seem to be literal.

Comment: @melpomene - Added that point in. I think the OP just expressed themselves poorly however. This should be downvoted to hell if they did not  :)

Comment: You are correct in that I did mean that `((void *)pb == (void *)pd)` (will update the question). But your counter example isn't appropriate as I am specifying that `D` is empty.